# How to debug dalvik vm crash: Class lookup Ljava/lang/NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I have a pure java (as in no native code) android app which is causing a dalvik vm crash when running on a api 7 device.  I have not seen this crash with other devices of higher versions.  If I start my app and leave it alone, the crash will usually occur within 10 minutes.

Looking through the java thread dump (which was too large to include here), most of the threads are in the sleep state and those that aren't look benign.

I'm quite used to debugging java issues on the android platform, but I don't know where to start with a native crash like this.

> 03-16 21:19:30.004 E/dalvikvm(6491): VM aborting
>   03-16 21:19:30.014 I/DEBUG   (6274): *****  ** *****  ** *****  ** *****  ** *****  ** ***
>   03-16 21:19:30.014 I/DEBUG   (6274): Build fingerprint: 'zt180/zt180/zt180/:2.1-update1/ERE27/eng.root.20101021.113523:eng/test-keys'
>   03-16 21:19:30.014 I/DEBUG   (6274): pid: 6491, tid: 6514  >>> com.dave.myapp <<<
>   03-16 21:19:30.014 I/DEBUG   (6274): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadd00d
>   03-16 21:19:30.014 I/DEBUG   (6274):  r0 00000390  r1 afe135e5  r2 0000000c  r3 deadd00d
>   03-16 21:19:30.014 I/DEBUG   (6274):  r4 00000026  r5 0013d250  r6 ad08b368  r7 00000000
>   03-16 21:19:30.014 I/DEBUG   (6274):  r8 ad0103c0  r9 ad089000  10 00000003  fp 492cbed8
>   03-16 21:19:30.014 I/DEBUG   (6274):  ip ad08b570  sp 492cbbe0  lr afe1459d  pc ad038a36  cpsr 20000030
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):          #00  pc 00038a36  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort)
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):          #01  pc 0005bb6a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):          #02  pc 0005bdde  /system/lib/libdvm.so   (dvmFindSystemClassNoInit)
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):          #03  pc 0005c2f2  /system/lib/libdvm.so   (dvmFindSystemClass)
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):          #04  pc 0003820a  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmThrowChainedException)
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):          #05  pc 000165fc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):          #06  pc 00013f58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274): code around pc:
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274): ad038a24 4808e9f2 6b9b5823 d0002b00 4b064798
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274): ad038a34 701c2426 ea5ef7d7 00052950 fffe3dfc
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274): ad038a44 fffe7230 00000390 deadd00d b510b40e
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274): code around lr:
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274): afe1458c 220ce008 2b005eab 1c28d003 47889901
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274): afe1459c 35544306 d5f43f01 2c006824 b003d1ee
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274): afe145ac bdf01c30 00025906 000000bc 1c0fb5f0
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274): stack:
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbba0  00000015
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbba4  afe13615  /system/lib/libc.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbba8  afe3a0b0  /system/lib/libc.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbac  afe3a05c  /system/lib/libc.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbb0  00000000
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbb4  afe1459d  /system/lib/libc.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbb8  492cbbcc
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbbc  afe135e5  /system/lib/libc.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbc0  ad08b368  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbc4  ad08b368  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbc8  0013d250  [heap]
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbcc  ad08b368  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbd0  00000000
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbd4  afe13647  /system/lib/libc.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbd8  ad08b368  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbdc  ad038a27  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274): #00 492cbbe0  ad08b368  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbe4  ad05bb6f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274): #01 492cbbe8  42973b52  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbec  ad08de18  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbf0  ad06e200  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.664 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbf4  00000000
>   03-16 21:19:31.684 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbf8  00000000
>   03-16 21:19:31.684 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbbfc  ad038189  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.684 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbc00  492cbca8
>   03-16 21:19:31.684 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbc04  ad08b368  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.684 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbc08  ad06e200  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:31.684 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbc0c  00000000
>   03-16 21:19:31.684 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbc10  00000000
>   03-16 21:19:31.684 I/DEBUG   (6274):     492cbc14  ad05bde3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
>   03-16 21:19:38.194 I/ActivityManager(2028): Process com.dave.myapp (pid 6491) has died.

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the stacktrace listed before VM aborts?

Comment: That's going to be the key.  There should never be a case where the VM aborts without telling you why (even back in API 7).

Comment: No, there are no stack traces due to exceptions.  Just the thread dump of all threads when the native crash occurs

Answer (score 0):

From the core dump, there are not only App Crash but also **Dalvik VM Crash**.
Aftering viewing the dalvik source code, your program's crash dump is:

1. dvmAbort()
2. vm/oo/Class.cpp: findClassNoInit
3. dvmFindSystemClassNoInit(......)

Android before invoking `dvmAbort`, the VM dump some information. You can check the error before the *CORE DUMP*.

And the code is:

```
/*   
 * We don't expect an exception to be raised at this point.  The
 * exception handling code is good about managing this.  This *can*
 * happen if a JNI lookup fails and the JNI code doesn't do any
 * error checking before doing another class lookup, so we may just
 * want to clear this and restore it on exit.  If we don't, some kinds
 * of failures can't be detected without rearranging other stuff.
 *
 * Most often when we hit this situation it means that something is
 * broken in the VM or in JNI code, so I'm keeping it in place (and
 * making it an informative abort rather than an assert).
 */
if (dvmCheckException(self)) {
    ALOGE("Class lookup %s attempted with exception pending", descriptor);
    ALOGW("Pending exception is:");
    dvmLogExceptionStackTrace();
    dvmDumpAllThreads(false);
    dvmAbort();
}
```